# Sql developer. Не видно полей в таблице

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-key

создал 9 полей в таблице из них видно только 7, не отображаются внешние ключи. Создал таблицу следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE List_Worker(
code Number(10) NOT NULL,
fam varchar2(55) NOT NULL,
im varchar2(55) NOT NULL,
otc varchar2(55) NOT NULL,
birthDay TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP,
workDay TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP,
CONSTRAINT code_pk2 PRIMARY KEY (code),
CONSTRAINT fk_codeDep FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES List_Department(code),
CONSTRAINT fk_codePos FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES List_Position(code),
firing char(1) CHECK 
(firing IN ('1', '2'))
```

);

Вот так выглядит таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы внешние ключи отображались ?

Comment: Внешние ключи, это не поля, они не будут отображаться как отдельные колонки никогда. У вас есть только поле code и в нем может быть только одно значение. А вот то что оно ссылается сразу на 2 таблицы - это очень странно. Это означает, что вы в это поле можете положить только такое значение, которое есть в обоих таблицах, указанных в ключах

Comment: Т.е. при заполнении таблицы мне игнорировать эти поля и работать только с теми, кто отображается ?

Comment: Повторяю, это не поля, их заполнять невозможно. Это ограничения для поля code, в которое вы теперь не сможете класть все что угодно

Comment: А чтобы создать поле (внешний ключ) нужно грубо говоря вот так написать: name type FK

Comment: поле code в вашей таблице вы уже сделали внешним ключом, причем сразу двумя внешними ключами. Представьте, есть у вас 5 коробков. И есть требование не класть в первый коробок спички с красными головками. Так вот коробки - это поля. А требование не класть чего то определенного в один из них - это внешний ключ.

Comment: Я вдруг понял, в чем ваша проблема, вы все таки примерно представляете зачем нужен ключ, просто ожидали, что поле обеспечивающее связь создастся само. Так вот, нет, само не создастся, объявляете например `dept_code number(10),` и отдельную строку `CONSTRAINT fk_codeDep FOREIGN KEY (dept_code) REFERENCES List_Department(code),`